# Expanding power series about a different point?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have a power series expanded about $z=0$ with radius of convergence $R=1$.

A power series like $f(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3..$

Now let's say I expand this about $z=\frac 3 4$. By using an inequality, the new radius of convergence is $R=\frac 1 4$.

But for $z=0$, $f(z)=1$. As I have just reordered terms, I conclude that the new power series should be equal to 1, and is converging for a point outside the radius of convergence.

Extending the same logic, I could rewrite any power series about any other point and have it converge at that point. What is the flaw in this argument?

Comment: The new power series does not converge for $z=0$, because it's interval of convergence is (1/2,1).

Comment: isn't it the same function but?

Comment: Have you looked at the series when expanding about $z=\frac34$?  Your argument is close  to saying that $4-4\times3+4\times3^2-4\times3^3+...= 1$ from the properties of a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding around $z=3/4$ you get:
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{k+1}\left(z-{3\over4}\right)^k.
$$
It is quite obvious that this doesn't converge for $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The power series around the point $\frac{3}{4}$ doesn't converge for $z = 0$. When you do a Taylor expansion around a point, you don't just rearrange the terms of a different power series.

You can write the following:
$$\sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty z^n = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty \left(z - \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{4}\right)^n = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty \left(\sum \limits_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n - k} \left(z - \frac{3}{4}\right)^k\right)$$

But you can't actually use associativity to break up the inner sum. This series is complicated, so I will show what I mean with another example:

$$0 = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty 0 = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty (1 + (-1))$$

These calculations are completely valid. Now one might be tempted to argue that the series converges absolutely, so the term can be rearranged as
$1 + (-1) + 1 + (-1) + \ldots = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n$. But this sequence obviously doesn't converge at all. This is why you need to be careful when trying to apply the associative and commutative property to (absolutely convergent) series.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have to expand the power series
$$\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + \dots $$
about a new point $z_0$ that lies outside its disk of convergence $|z| = 1$.
The final result has to be a power series in $(z - z_0)$ that computes to the
same infinite sum as the one we start with.
$$ \frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{1}{1-z_0 - (z - z_0)} = \Bigg[\frac{1}{1-z_0}\Bigg]
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{z-z_0}{1-z_0}} $$
For convenience, define the following new variables,
$$ w_0 = \frac{1}{1-z_0} \qquad\qquad w = \frac{z - z_0}{1 - z_0} $$
Now the LHS has become
$$ \frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{w_0}{1 - w} $$
The RHS can now be expressed as
$$ \frac{w_0}{1 - w} = w_0\ \Bigg[ 1 + w + w^2 + w^3 + \dots \Bigg]$$
$$ 1 + z + z^2 + \dots = \frac{1}{1-z_0}\ \Bigg[ 1 + \Big( \frac{z-z_0}
{1-z_0} \Big) + \Big( \frac{z - z_0}{1-z_0} \Big)^2 + 
 \Big( \frac{z - z_0}{1-z_0} \Big)^3 + \dots \Bigg] $$

Comment: Cross verify this solution by asking wolframalpha to expand the geometric series about a point a + bi of your choice.